# How to send data from a for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a for loop and wanted to send data to other component using @Input event emitter.
But the problem is i am only receiving the last value in the component template.

Please advice, help needed.

Parent component TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component(
  {
    selector      : 'parent-component',
    templateUrl   : './parent.component.html',
  }
)
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    public data;

  constructor () {
  }

  getData(){
    for (let i = 1; i <= i; i++) {          
      this.data =  i;
    }
  }
}
```

Parent Component Template

```
<child-component [data]="data"></child-component>
```

Child Component TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html'
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input()
  data;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   // i am receiving a value 1,2, 3...10
  }
}
```

Child Component template

```
            <div>{{data}}</div>
```

I am using a loop in parent component for getting data in child component which I have to show in child component which is not reflecting in child component.
Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us what you've attempted already.

Comment: How are you trying to send it currently?

Comment: using `@Input` from parent component updating the value in for loop and receiving in child component. in template `{{data}}`, this data template is showing only 10, i.e the last value of the loop.But in ngOnChanges() hook i can see the updated values

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Comment: Please edit the whole loop (and any other relevant code) into your question.  That isn't really enough to go on.

Comment: See the [part 2](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#selecting-a-hero) and [part 3](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) in tutorial

Comment: We are receiving data in `ChildComponent` `ngOnChanges ` method and receiving values as 1,2,3 ... 10 but in template we are not  receiving 1,2,3 ... 10, just the last value 10. Is there a way by which we can reflect the changes in template

Answer (score 0):

Input bindings only see the *current* value of the data they're bound to.  If you were able to slow down the loop, you'd see the bound value go through 1, 2, 3, and so on, but only one value at a time.

If you want it to get all the values from the loop, you'll need to use an array or something similar.  For example:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    public data = [];

  constructor () {
  }

  getData(){
    // I assume this was supposed to be 10, not i, or else you get an infinite loop
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {           
      this.data.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```